# Autofilter by inputting array by selecting a range of crieteria vba excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range, autofilter

***edit # 1***
I am trying to autofilter a sheet based on the criteria as an array, the array values are selected by using the dialog box to select the range.Also, this dialog box's intent is to select multiple unsorted values that need to be sorted.Here is the code:

```
Sub Hyperlink_opener()
Dim Selrng As Range
Dim srch_cr As Variant
Set Selrng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

srch_cr = Array(Selrng)
Sheets("DocLog").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$F").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=srch_cr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
'ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15

End Sub
```

This is currently not searching for the cell that i selected and is giving me an error Autofilter method of range class failed.

Comment: You can use an array. This post of mine may be of interest: http://yoursumbuddy.com/autofilter-vba-operator-parameters/

Comment: i think i am having problem with converting a range to an array as i did make some change and i am still getting an error.Error is Autofilter error of Range Class Failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it as long as your selected range contains text, or numbers stored as text:

```
Sub Hyperlink_opener()
Dim Selrng As Range
Dim srch_cr As Variant

Set Selrng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
srch_cr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Selrng)
Sheets("DocLog").Range("$A:$F").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=srch_cr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Note that you need to transpose the range to turn it to a single-dimension range. Also, no need to `Select` the sheet, just refer to it.

If you have numbers that need to be filtered, you can either store them as text in your filter range or convert them to text in the code by parsing the array.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `Operator:=xlOr`, I think you'd like to filter on multiple criteria.

According to [Microsoft's docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (for Excel 2010), you can have 2 criteria, and the `Operator:=` tells it what to do with the two of them. In your case, the code would be:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$a:$F").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
             Criteria1:=Srch_Cr(1), Criteria2:=Srch_Cr(2), Operator:=xlOr
```

You cannot simply pass an array to the Criteria1 parameter and assume the `.AutoFilter` function will figure out what to do with it.

Comment: I have more than 2 fields that i want  to sort through on the same column, that is why i added the range selection dialog box. And the Or command is  tomake sure that all the fields within the slected range are visible in the autofiter. Since the number of criterias is dynamic, does that mean for 100 docs that i want to find, i will have to write criteria 100 times rather than inputing them into an array???

Comment: Passing an array to the `.AutoFilter` is not a feature I'm aware of. It also doesn't seem to fit with the documentation (referenced) for Criteria1: `The criteria (a string; for example, "101").` If you have an example of it working, I'd be most interested in seeing that, because it does sound _very_ useful!